# How to copy method body of a particular method to another method in different class using ASM

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I am just starting to learn ASM (Java library). I want to know how I can copy the method body of a particular method from a class file A to another class file B. However, the class file A is generated while source file B is going to be compiled in B.class. Is there a way during the generation of class file B, we can insert the method body from class file A to B.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to visit the method you want to copy while creating the generated class. For the visited method, you the delegate all method calls to the generated class's method writer.

Do however note that this does not necessarily work. The generated class might not declare the same fields or have access to the same members. This would raise a verification error.